# Destroy BroadcastReceiver in onResume()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have onResume() and onDestroy() methods in my MainActivity. How can I detroy the registerReceiver in the onResume() method. I tried to assign it to variable but without success.

```js
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {

   registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    check_wifi_available();

   }
  }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
  super.onResume();

 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  unregisterReceiver();
  super.onDestroy();
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy the registerReceiver" ?

Comment: Is there no need to destroy it or pause it? I thought I have to do that like in BroadcastReceiver class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the android documentation:

> If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation,
>   you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive
>   intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system
>   overhead)

Define your receiver as a class variable like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { 
 @Override 
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     check_wifi_available(); 
   } 
 }
```

Then implements the onPause() / onResume() methods like this:

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() { 
     super.onResume(); 
     registerReceiver(mReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
} 

@Override 
protected void onPause() { 
    super.onPause(); 
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
 }
```

No need to unregister it in onDestroy() method.

Comment: Where shall I define the class variable mRceiver? in in the onCreate() method?

Comment: Either in your onCreate or directly in your class, outside of any methods: "private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = [...]"

Comment: @MrAsker You can only put one answer as the correct answer.

Comment: can you help me please I am not getting result if I call the method"check_wifi_available();" from the onReceive thougth the method works well if I call it from the "onLocationChanged" emthod? I do not have to add something in my manifest.xml file?

Comment: @MrAsker I suggest you post an other question on stackoverflow and mark this one as solved. Post a link here and i will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Define the receiver in your class' attributes :

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
};
```

and these methods :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("your package name"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```